# Better way to inject progress bar into GridSearchCV

Tags: python, oop, machine-learning, scikit-learn, progress-bar

Inspired by [Getting progress updates from GridSearchCV with scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594642/getting-progress-updates-from-gridsearchcv-with-scikit-learn) I've added the following to my sklearn `GridSearchCV` script.

##### Explanation

1. I find the total number of fits being performed by `GridSearchCV`
2. I create a custom score wrapper around an existing sklearn scorer (recall), whcih contains the `bar()` function from [alive-bar](https://github.com/rsalmei/alive-progress) progress bar package
3. I override the default score for GridSearchCV with my custom scorer
4. use the `with alive_bar` method when running fit on grid search.

This gives me a correct progress bar for my grid search.

```
from sklearn.metrics import (recall_score, make_scorer)
from sklearn.model_selection import (GridSearchCV, ParameterGrid)
from alive_progress import alive_bar

num_folds = 3
total_fits = len(ParameterGrid(params)) * num_folds


def my_recall_score(*args):
    score = recall_score(*args)
    bar()
    return score

sc_cust = make_scorer(my_recall_score, greater_is_better=True)

grid_pipeline = GridSearchCV(pipe, params, n_jobs=1, cv=num_folds, scoring=sc_cust)
with alive_bar(total_fits) as bar:
    grid_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

##### The Problem

- To use this method, I would have to create a custom scorer for every metric I want to use in sklearn, rather than using the built in detection methods.
- It is quite an ugly patch
- There doesn't seem to be a good 2022 answer for this problem, I'm open to other style solutions for a progress bar. The verbose option is not helpful for this task.
- The object is not pickleable and does not work with >1 n_jobs
- In addition, I have created a custom verbose > 999 set of code I put inside `sklearn.model_selection._validation._fit_and_score`:

```
progress_msg = ""
    if verbose > 998:
        params_msg = f"; {candidate_progress[0]+1}/{candidate_progress[1]}"
    else:
```

and

```
if not verbose > 998:
    end_msg = f"[CV{progress_msg}] END "
else:
    end_msg = ''
```

which also simplifies the output to just a running count, but this prints a lot to the console which wouldn't be needed with a progress bar. My current work is trying to turn this into a progress bar.

##### What I've tried

- The above hack
- The linked SO answers below (and a few more)
- Digging into the GridSearchCV code, but the way the code is written with the parallel element I'm not sure how to add this idea in
- verbose > 3 does give a count of complete / total, but prints a lot of other text with it - I'm planning to dig into that code and see what can be fixed

Other SO answers that **do not** answer this:

- [Sklearn, gridsearch: how to print out progress during the execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121018/sklearn-gridsearch-how-to-print-out-progress-during-the-execution) - from 8 years ago, verbose doesn't give a progress bar, `GridSearchCVProgressBar` is broken.
- [GridSearchCV progress in Jupiter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495946/gridsearchcv-progress-in-jupiter-notebook) - prints in terminal not notebook,

Comment: Look at this code:

https://github.com/pactools/pactools/blob/1e95893bdfedf6e646749cf380c3815d4165bd9a/pactools/utils/progress_bar.py#L7

It's exactly what you need. The library pactools has the GridSearchCV with progress done for you.